# Print to pos thermal printer using tcp web-application

Tags: javascript, thermal-printer, pos

I have a task to create a web application on javascript/typescript that could print to the pos printer directly using TCP or some other protocol. Everything has to happen on the customer's device not using the server. The customer should be able to print in his local network

Testing on EPSON TM-T20III
I tried using WebSocket for that but it sends its header to the printer

```
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.171:9100/");
    console.log(ws);ws.onopen = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        ws.send('test test test');};

    ws.onclose = function(e) {
        console.log("Done");};
    ws.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Error");};
}
```

I get this from the printer:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.171:9100
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh: Intel Mac OS
X 10 15 7) ApplewebKit/537.35 (KHTML, like Geck
o) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost:4300
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9,lt;q=0.8,ru;q=0.
7
Sec-WebSocket-Key:YTtnLHd6T+4YEEzlyro16Q==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; cl
ent max _window _bits
GET / HTTP/1.
Host: 192.168.1.171:9100
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS
X 10 15 7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Geck
0) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost: 4300
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9,1t;0=0.8,ru;q=0.
Sec-WebSocket-Key:4840Pq0V1LHpgLeZZadhEw==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; cl
ent max _window_bits
```

tried using socket.net

```
const Net = require("net");

let name = this.host + ":" + this.port;
    let printer = Net.connect(
        {
            // host: this.host,
            host: '192.168.1.171',
            port: this.port || 9100,
            timeout: this.timeout || 3000
        },

    );
    
function execute (resolve) {
    printer.write('buffer', null, function () {
        resolve("Data sent to printer: " + name);
        printer.destroy();
    });
}
execute();
```

But then I need to start a Node server on the client's device which is too complicated for the client.

I'm looking for other options, but can't find anything. A lot of things are blocked for security reasons. Can anybody help?

Comment: WebSockets aren't raw TCP connections. And you can't make them from browsers.

Comment: @gre_gor Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should use the javascrpt SDK https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=57.

I'm currently struggling with some CORS stuff. I'm not getting the access-control-allow-origin-header when connecting to TM-T20IIIL (with TM-T20II I have it working)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I searched more on the internet and found this solution, which works brilliant!

Comment: @Vltas Svigaris could you solve this? do you have an example?

Comment: Yes it works, but Epson's SDK is not going to work with other brand printers, the standard `ESCPOS`` implemented by many printer brands, we need to make correnction / send cmd to printer directly (without Epson SDK) to write driver following ESCPOS so that can work with other brands too. Is anybody know how to send ESCPOS commands to the Epson T20III model from browser?