# How to make connection with Thermal printer from browser and send ESCPOS print commands

Tags: tcp, printing, thermal-printer, epson, posprinter

We're using Epson TM-** series printers, need to print to that from web but can't use Epson's JS SDK because we want to write a driver(like) that emplements ESCPOS standard, Many other brand printers support this standard, So our driver will support those printers too. As the Epson's SDK is not going to connect to other brands, we are not going to use their SDK.

Following this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73587774/print-to-pos-thermal-printer-using-tcp-web-application) it is clear that making a printer connection from web is definitely possible (without vendor SDK).Just need to know how?

There's other limitations too, which need to be overcome. like- now days all website is served under SSL, the local printer's address like `http://192.168.192.168`, so thats not SSL, so browsers most likely block this connectiong, if anybody has solution to this, please share.

Comment: Don't their mechanisms and support depend on the vendor and model? Even the ESC/POS commands themselves are mostly compatible with EPSON from other vendors, but there are many small differences. EPSON itself also has different functional details and support depending on the model. It's best to contact each printer vendor for more information, rather than waiting for someone to answer it on a Q&A site like here. [Epson TM-T88V-i SSL Certificate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50116786/9014308), [Epson ePos Javascript SDK: TM-P80 not working...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73987119/9014308)